# Select a three columns jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, html

How can I select three columns using jQuery or CSS, for example:

This code below:

```
<script> //In this part I try to select the columns but not functions
  $('GvGrid').slice(1, 3).css("backgroundColor", "yellow");
  //$("GvGrid td:nth-child(13):gt(1)").css("backgroundColor", "yellow");
</script>  

<table id="TblCom" runat="server" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <asp:GridView ID="Gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ClientIDMode="Static" RowStyle-CssClass="GvGrid" CellPadding="1">
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="GvGrid" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <Columns>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="MES_ANIO" HeaderText="MES"></asp:BoundField>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="PERIODO" HeaderText="PERIODO"></asp:BoundField>
          <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="CVE_USUARIO" HeaderText="USUARIO" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="/Ventas/RepArchivoPersonalAuxiliarEmp.aspx?prospecto={0}" DataTextField="USUARIO"> //Select this
            <ControlStyle CssClass="Texto" />
            <ControlStyle CssClass="Texto" />
          </asp:HyperLinkField>
          <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="/Contraloria/Nomina/RepComisionesDetalle.aspx?FechaI={0:d}&FechaF={1:d}&CveUsuario={2}&CveRol={3}&TipoProducto=ECO&Estatus={4}&Acum={5}&Pagada={6}&CvePlaza={7}&CveTipoQuincena={8}" DataTextField="ECO" DataTextFormatString="{0:###}" HeaderText="ECO"> //Select this
          </asp:HyperLinkField>
          <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="/Contraloria/Nomina/RepComisionesDetalle.aspx?FechaI={0:d}&FechaF={1:d}&CveUsuario={2}&CveRol={3}&TipoProducto=A&Estatus={4}&Acum={5}&Pagada={6}&CvePlaza={7}&CveTipoQuincena={8}" DataTextField="A" DataTextFormatString="{0:###}" HeaderText="A">
          </asp:HyperLinkField>
          <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields=""                      DataNavigateUrlFormatString="/Contraloria/Nomina/RepComisionesDetalle.aspx?FechaI={0:d}&FechaF={1:d}&CveUsuario={2}&CveRol={3}&TipoProducto=B1&Estatus={4}&Acum={5}&Pagada={6}&CvePlaza={7}&CveTipoQuincena={8}" DataTextField="B1" DataTextFormatString="{0:###}" HeaderText="B1"> //Select this                                 </asp:HyperLinkField>
        </Columns>
      </asp:GridView>                               
      <br />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My page Inherits master page, the script above tried to select any pars columns but when the page load I can not see the style in the rows
thanks for yours comments.

Comment: jQuery works at the client on the *rendered* html.  Please post the rendered html text.

Comment: many of your .NET components render custom html, is impossible to see what the problem is...

Answer (score 1):

1. You are selecting 'GvGrid', which is a class. You should use
   '.GvGrid' to select the class.
2. Maybe the jQuery runs before the dom is loaded. You should wrap the
   script in `$(document).ready(function(){})`.

I would do like this:

```
<script> //In this part i try to select the columns but not functions
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.GvGrid').slice(1, 3).css("backgroundColor", "yellow");
            //$("GvGrid td:nth-child(13):gt(1)").css("backgroundColor", "yellow");
    });
</script>
```